# How To Hook To Commerce Add To Cart Button After Add?

Tags: commerce, rules

I'm trying to ask the same question in another way... hoping I can get an answer.

I have a function I need to trigger AFTER the product is added to the cart.

When I added a PHP function to a Pricing Rule it seems to execute -before- the product is added.

The Commerce website says that the a Pricing Rule may be triggered before or after the line item is added but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a rules event that fires when a product is added to the cart, which is called after the price calculation one, check [commerce_cart_product_add](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_product_add/DC) function.

It uses [rules_invoke_all](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_invoke_all/7), which means that you can either run actions on this event or invoke the hook directly, `hook_commerce_cart_product_add` normally.

```
// Invoke the product add event with the newly saved or updated line item.
rules_invoke_all('commerce_cart_product_add', $order, $product, $quantity, $line_item);
```